# Python 3 pandas Marking data in dataframes using strings vs Regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

So I have 2 ways of doing the same thing and was wondering which one is more efficient:

The first way loads a list from a text file or array and marks up a dataframe using the list:

```
import pandas as pd

ban_list = ['Al Gore', 'Kim jong-un','Kim jong un','Kim Jong Un', 'Al Sharpton','Kim jong il', 'Richard Johnson', 'Dick Johnson']

df=pd.DataFrame({'Users': [ 'Al Gore', 'Kim jong il', 'Kim jong un', 'Al Sharpton', 'James', 'Richard Johnson', 'Bill Gates', 'Alf pig', 'Dick Johnson', 'Python Monte'],
                 'Time': ['D','D','N','D','L','N', 'N','L','L','N']})

df['Banned'] = ''


for i in range(len(ban_list)):
    df.loc[df.Users.str.contains(ban_list[i]) & (df.Banned == ''),'Banned'] = 'Yes'
```

The second way uses regex patterns instead of a list of names

```
import pandas as pd

ban_list = ['^(?i)Al(\s)(Gore|Sharpton)$', '^(?i)Kim\sjong(\s|-)(il|un)$', '^(?i)(Dick|Richard)\sJohnson$']

df=pd.DataFrame({'Users': [ 'Al Gore', 'Kim jong il', 'Kim jong un', 'Al Sharpton', 'James', 'Richard Johnson', 'Bill Gates', 'Alf pig', 'Dick Johnson', 'Python Monte'],
                 'Time': ['D','D','N','D','L','N', 'N','L','L','N']})

df['Banned'] = ''


for i in range(len(ban_list)):
    df.loc[df.Users.str.contains(ban_list[i]) & (df.Banned == ''),'Banned'] = 'Yes'
```

Both set of code works and does about the same thing. So far the problems are the first one can is not case sensitive and the second one has a warning `UserWarning: This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract. " groups, use str.extract.", UserWarning)`

The array in the first way loads a large list and the second way has regex with multiple steps. Which one should I use for efficiency? or are there other ways to improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems a little cleaner (at least to me) to use `isin` since you have a nice list of the banned users (you can then map the True/False to Yes/'':

```
df['Banned'] = df.Users.isin(ban_list).map({True:'Yes',False:''})
print df

  Time            Users Banned
0    D          Al Gore    Yes
1    D      Kim jong il    Yes
2    N      Kim jong un    Yes
3    D      Al Sharpton    Yes
4    L            James       
5    N  Richard Johnson    Yes
6    N       Bill Gates       
7    L          Alf pig       
8    L     Dick Johnson    Yes
9    N     Python Monte
```

Of course, if True/False is good enough you can just to the first part of the command:

```
df['Banned'] = df.Users.isin(ban_list)
print df

  Time            Users Banned
0    D          Al Gore   True
1    D      Kim jong il   True
2    N      Kim jong un   True
3    D      Al Sharpton   True
4    L            James  False
5    N  Richard Johnson   True
6    N       Bill Gates  False
7    L          Alf pig  False
8    L     Dick Johnson   True
9    N     Python Monte  False
```

**Edit**: If you had a second list I would do it as follows:

```
Adminlist = ['Bill Gates']
df['Banned'] = (df.Users.isin(ban_list).map({True:'Yes',False:''}) +
                df.Users.isin(Adminlist).map({True:'Admin',False:''}))
print df

  Time            Users Banned
0    D          Al Gore    Yes
1    D      Kim jong il    Yes
2    N      Kim jong un    Yes
3    D      Al Sharpton    Yes
4    L            James       
5    N  Richard Johnson    Yes
6    N       Bill Gates  Admin
7    L          Alf pig       
8    L     Dick Johnson    Yes
9    N     Python Monte
```

Comment: this works with the first case but not the regex case

Comment: Yes, `isin` is not going to work with regex. Sorry, I thought it was clear it applied to your first approach.

Comment: If I add another list `isin` would not work either. Like if I add `Adminlist = ['Bill Gates']` and `df['Banned'] = df.Users.isin(Adminlist).map({True:'Admin'})` I guess I would have to use a merge function then.